# Can not get node value using simplexml in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newsItem>
       <contentSet>
              <inlineXML contenttype="application/xhtml+xml">
                     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                            <div>
                                   <h1>St. Augustine Gold and Copper Limited: Update on Recent Corporate Developments</h1>
                               </div>
                      </html>
               </inlineXML>
       </contentSet>
</newsItem>
```

I want to get the value in  using with the following code with no problem

```
if (file_exists('example.newsml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('example.newsml');

    $html= (string) $xml->{'contentSet'}->{'inlineXML'}->{'html'}->{'div'}->{'h1'};

    echo $html; 

} else {
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}
```

I tried to get the html from the node but get empty result.

```
$content = (string) $xml->{'contentSet'}->{'inlineXML'}->{'html'};
echo $content;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the node as XML

```
echo $xml->contentSet->inlineXML->html->saveXml();
```

Output: https://eval.in/205477

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <div>
    <h1>St. Augustine Gold and Copper Limited: Update on Recent Corporate Developments</h1>
  </div>
</html>
```